# Simple SQL join in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a users table and a pools table. The users table has a column called facebook_id which I want to set to be the primary_key.  The pools table has a column called creator_facebook_id.

I want to perform a simple join where users.facebook_id = pools.creator_facebook_id

I'm trying to do this through active record by placing the following code in my models

```
class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "facebook_id"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pools, :foreign_key => "creator_facebook_id"
end
```

Then I when I have a list of pools I'd like to be able to do something like this

```
pool.user.name
```

And return the name (stored in the users table) associated with the pool. This must be quite simple where am I going wrong?

Comment: The foreign_key should be the same value in both association mappings (creator_facebook_id). Getting ActiveRecord to use facebook_id as the primary key of the User class is a different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually have set `facebook_id` as the primary key on the Users table, you will need to inform Rails of this. There is a `:primary_key` option available for associations, so you could use this on your Pool model:

```
belongs_to :user, :primary_key => 'facebook_id', :foreign_key => 'creator_facebook_id'
```

That should allow you to use `Pool.user`. Unfortunately, getting ActiveRecord to play nicely with non-standard primary keys is another issue entirely. I suggest you just let it do it's thing with the `id` column being the primary key and add an index on your `facebook_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the class name.

```
class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => "facebook_id"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pools, :class_name => 'Pool', :foreign_key => "creator_facebook_id"
end
```

Comment: These are the default values for the class names, so this won't help.

Answer (score 0):

migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users, :primary_key => 'facebook_id' do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end

class CreatePools < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :pools do |t|
      t.integer :creator_facebook_id
      t.string :name
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :pools
  end
end
```

models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key 'facebook_id'
  has_many :pools, :foreign_key => "creator_facebook_id"
end

class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "creator_facebook_id"
end
```

this will allow for:

```
pool.user.name
```

tested with sqlite and rails 3.0.7